# SQL Server 2008 Express 

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

I am designing a database which would have a table (containing contact details like `Contactid` `name Number` and `address`)

I want to add notes every time when a contact visits my office, with date and time.

So I created another table `visit` (`Visitid, Visit date, Notes, Contactsid`)

But I am unable to create a relationship as one contact can have multiple notes.

What I want is?

When I select a `contact` in the UI then it shows me the visit history and option to enter new visit notes

Thnx

Comment: what UI are you using for accessing the database? Why are you referring to SQL Express (I'm guessing MS SQL Server Express?) in the caption, but to mysql in the tag, which one is it you're using?

Comment: I will use vb 2010 express for ui and i am using MS Sql Server express

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite follow - you should be able to definitely establish a foreign key relationship between `Visit` and `Contact` like this:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Visit
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Visit_Contact
  FOREIGN KEY(ContactID) REFERENCES dbo.Contact(ContactID)
```

This links each visit to exactly one contact - but each contact can have any number of visits, of course.

To get all visit for a given contact, when you select it in your UI, you'd use something like:

```
SELECT VisitID, VisitDate, Notes
FROM dbo.Visit
WHERE ContactID = @ContactID
```

and then you'd have to set the `@ContactID` parameter to the proper value (the ID of the contact chosen in your UI) before executing this SELECT.